# sending 400 level error to ajax callback from action causing strange behavior

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I have a view with two partials in it that use ajax to post their forms to actions. The onsuccess callback redirects the user to another url. However I don't want this onsuccess function to be called when the modelstate is not valid. I've tried returning a 400 level error from my controller to trigger the onfailure function but it causes some weird behavior and the validation errors don't display. Here's my code

Action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
    [DisableCache]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl ="/") //This is the view that contains the two other partial views.
    {
        var path = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(returnUrl);
        var url = new Uri(Request.Url, path).AbsoluteUri;
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = url;
        return View();
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult _LoginPartial()
    {
        return PartialView(new LoginModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult _LoginPartial(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password,    persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
        {
            return PartialView();
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        Response.StatusCode = 400;
        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

Login View:

```
<hgroup class="title">
<h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

 @section CustomScripts {
     @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){
         <script type ="text/javascript">
             function OnSuccess() {
                 var returnUrl = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.ReturnUrl))
                 window.location = returnUrl;
             }
             function OnFailure() {
                alert("Fail");
            }
        </script>
    }
}

<section id="loginForm">

@{
     if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
        <h2>Use a Creative Works account to log in.</h2>
        @Html.Action("_LoginPartial")
        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ResetPassword")
     }
}
</section>
<section id ="RegisterForm">
@{
    if(!WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated){
        <span>Don't have an account? Make one!</span>
        @Html.Action("RegisterPartial", new { returnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
    }
}
</section>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

_LoginPartial view

```
@model Cwo.Domain.Entities.LoginModel


@{
ViewBag.Title = "LoginPartial";
}
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("_LoginPartial", 
new AjaxOptions(){UpdateTargetId = "loginForm", 
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, OnSuccess = "OnSuccess", OnFailure = "OnFailure"
})) {    

 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>
    }
```

The formatting got kinda messed up pasting in here, sorry about that. Instead of an alert("fail") response I want the validation errors to display. If there's a better way than returning a 400 level error from the action please teach me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think another way to word you problem is you don't want the contents of the onsuccess function to be executed? if this is the case then move your @if (ViewData.ModelState.IsValid){ ... } to inside the OnSuccess function. if state is invalid that function would have no guts so nothing gets done.

personally I like keeping javascript separate from razor...even more, the javascript should reside in its own js file. in this case you could use razor to set a bool javascript variable to a function or object constructor, which would then do your success work only if variable was true.

Comment: Thanks man ill try this tomorrow. I don't know why I didn't think of putting the if condition inside the actual js. I realize its probably not the most optimal to mix razor and js, but it's such a tiny piece of code I didn't think it merited a separate js file.